# getting error while changing the orientation of the mobile when page is loading its components in android?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

i have one page opened in which i have taken information from the user... but if i change the orientation of the mobile all the information filled in the textview disappears... how would i make information saved in the textview no matter how many times user changes orientation... by the away i am using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in all activities... please some body suggest something...

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

better try out this way  iam not sure in my application this was working....

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saveinstance invoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

Comment: this is not working ... super.onCreate(outState); is written above you state ment... if i comment your life it works... do i have to call your line when i am changing the orientation...